# $conexion = new PDO($url,$usuario,$pass); de da null cuando hago un require_one;

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo una página conexion.php que hace una conexión a la base de datos usando PDO. Mi problema es cuando requiero esta conexion en una función desde otra pagina llamada modelo.php que es donde tengo todas las consultas. El caso es que si hago un vardump de conexion en conexion.php me devuelve un objeto PDO, pero si lo hago dentro de la función que uso en modelo.php me retorna null.
Esto es conexion.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la funcion.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estos los errores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Además tengo un controlador frontal que llama a modelo.php y un controlador que llama a la función que se muestra en la captura.

Alguien me puede echar un cable.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ten cuidado con los typo. Has puesto "dbename" en la `$url`

Ten cuidado con las variables. La función existeUsuario() pide un $usuario que este se sobrescribe al usar el require_once porque el $usuario te lo va a devolver como root.

En el archivo donde está la función yo pondría al menos el `<?php` ya que al probarlo me devuelve todo como un String; Tomando como HTML

Y eso es lo que puedo decir del código que proporcionas.
Aquí te lo envío corregido.

conexion.php:

```
<?php
$url='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tareaglobal';
$user='root';
$pass='';

try{
    $conexion = new PDO($url,$user,$pass);
}catch( PDOException $e){
    print "Error".$e->getMessage()."<br />";
    die();
}
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
function existeUsuario($usuario){
    require_once 'conexion.php';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tareaglobal.usuarios WHERE usuario=".$usuario;

    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($conexion);
    $resultado =$conexion->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute();

    if($resultado->rowCount()>=1){
        echo "usuario encontrado";
        return true;
    }else{
        echo "usuario No encontrado";
        return false;
    }
$conexion=null;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

PS: En la toma de decisión IF he añadido un echo para cada elección, así puedes saber que camino ha seguido.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya quedó resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Aca de te comparto capturas de codigo con PDO

- Conexion
- Modelo

**La conexión**

[image: Conexion usando PDO con php7]

**El modelo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias.